# navigation menu scroll functionality only for screens above 750px

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a panel with navigation, I added a scrolling style to this panel, like slides, everything works as it should, but the only thing is that this functionality should only work when the screen size is higher than the mobile one, I set it to 750px

I tried adding this to the beginning of the script

```
if ($(document).width() > 750) {
```

It seems to work, but the problem is that it is applied only when the page is refreshed, and if you just drag the screen width, then everything does not work correctly, let's say I changed the screen width from desktop to mobile without refreshing the page, and the script still continues to work until do not refresh the page

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function active_tab_highlight_pos(init = false, resize = false) {
    let nav_tabs = $('.nav-tabs');
    let active_tab = $(nav_tabs).find('.active');

    let nav_tabs_pos = {
      x: $(nav_tabs).offset().left,
      y: $(nav_tabs).offset().top
    }

    let active_tab_pos = {
      x: $(active_tab).offset().left - nav_tabs_pos.x,
      y: $(active_tab).offset().top - nav_tabs_pos.y,
      w: $(active_tab).outerWidth(),
      h: $(active_tab).outerHeight()
    }

    if (init) {
      $(nav_tabs).prepend('<li class="active-highlight"></li>');
    }

    let active_highlight = $(nav_tabs).find('.active-highlight');

    if (resize) {
        $(active_highlight).css({
        'transition': 'none'
      });
    } else {
        $(active_highlight).css({
        'transition': 'all .5s ease'
      });
 
    }

    $(active_highlight).css({
      'width': active_tab_pos.w + 'px',
      'height': active_tab_pos.h + 'px',
      'left': active_tab_pos.x + 'px',
      'top': active_tab_pos.y + 'px'
    });
  }

  active_tab_highlight_pos(true);
  
  $(window).on('resize', function() {
    active_tab_highlight_pos(false, true);

  });

  $('[data-bs-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function() {
    active_tab_highlight_pos();
  });
});
```

```css
.nav-tabs {
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs > li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a {
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #000;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: color 0.5s ease;
}

.nav-tabs > li > a.active {
  color: #FFF;
}

.nav-tabs > .active-highlight {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  background: #A700FF;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.info {
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#list1" id="list1-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list1" role="tab" aria-controls="list1" aria-selected="true" class="active">List 1</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#list2" id="list2-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list2" role="tab" aria-controls="list2" aria-selected="false">List 2</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#list3" id="list3-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list3" role="tab" aria-controls="list3" aria-selected="false">List 3</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#list4" id="list4-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#list4" role="tab" aria-controls="list4" aria-selected="false">List 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="list1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list1-tab" class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="info">List 1 info</div>
  </div>
  <div id="list2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list2-tab" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="info">List 2 info</div>
  </div>
  <div id="list3" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list3-tab" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="info">List 3 info</div>
  </div>
  <div id="list4" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="list4-tab" class="tab-pane">
    <div class="info">List 4 info</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I tried adding this to the beginning of the script"_ - meaning what, exactly - even before the `$(document).ready(function() {` line ...? That would not make much sense.

Comment: @CBroe after it, before the function

Comment: Then it will still only check _once_, when `$(document).ready` fires. You would need to perform this check _inside_ the function, and then decide whether that currently needs to do something, or not - or maybe even _reverse_ something that was previously done for the "other case".

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.innerWidth instead of $(document).width()

```
if(window.innerWidth > 750) {
  // Your code here
}
```

And then,

```
window.addEventListener("resize", () => 
  {
    if(window.innerWidth > 750) {
       // Your code here
    }
  });
```

Comment: Remember to remove eventlistener while window width < 750

Comment: Not required because if it's removed, then on resizing again, the listener won't be there. You mean remove scroll on width<750 ?

Comment: Opps, You are right.